# Create user profile pages with ActiveAdmin in rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, activeadmin, user-profile

Can someone give me advise on If it is possible to create user profiles with ActiveAdmin?
I'm learning rails by doing and I wan't to build an app were the users go to private profile page after log_in.

I've built basic blog apps using ActiveAdmin, but now I want more.

The Idea is to put personalised material to each user profile via ActiveAdmin.
I'll create the user_profiles and hand the sign_in info to the user.

I've bee searching the internet for tutorials on the topic but with no luck yet, It would be nice if someone could inform me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/How-to-add-User-Accounts-for-users-to-administer-their-personal-accounts  There are various other links to sample apps and how-to articles on the wiki also.